# Sass-Rails @import, do global imports have to be imported in each stylesheet or just application.scss?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass

In our current project app, I hope to eventually get to cleaning up our CSS/SASS assets. As I was reviewing what we have, we have tons of @imports all over our files, i.e. some global variables are contained in an seperate file and we import that file in several other stylesheets at the top. However, in our `platform.scss` (pretty much our `application.scss`), at the top I call to @import all our global variable files. Is it necessary to @import other stylesheets at the top of each stylesheet that requires it or could I just potentially only @import those global stylesheets at the top of our `platform.scss` so I only have to import once.

A snippet from my Gemfile.lock.

```
rails (4.1.14.2)
  actionmailer (= 4.1.14.2)
  actionpack (= 4.1.14.2)
  actionview (= 4.1.14.2)
  activemodel (= 4.1.14.2)
  activerecord (= 4.1.14.2)
  activesupport (= 4.1.14.2)
  bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
  railties (= 4.1.14.2)
  sprockets-rails (~> 2.0)
sass (3.4.13)
 sass-rails (5.0.1)
  railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
  sass (~> 3.1)
  sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
  sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
  tilt (~> 1.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can potentially import it once in the beginning of the global style sheet! Just make sure you import it at the very top or else another style sheet that is dependent on the import might not work. The order matters.